# Making wordpress template mobile friendly

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, w3.css

I have created a custom  page-template with child theme of Official WordPress **twenty-seventeen theme**.

However i have problem on mobile devices, the pages are not mobile friendly and i get the popup from chrome to **make the page mobile friendly** and indeed the content is not readable at all on mobile devices.

I am trying make it friendly using [W3.css framework](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp), how can i do the content mobile friendly with w3.css or just some css or any other library? Below is the code of the template. [Here](https://webdominar.xyz/samples/lialapithi-sample/pink-chanel-suit/) it is the template-page i use and is not mobile friendly.

```
   <?php
/**
 * Template Name: More info template
 *
 * Description: A custom template for displaying a fullwidth layout with no sidebar.
 *
 * @package Twenty Seventeen Child
 */
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div style="padding:5px;" class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main info-template"  class="site-main w3-padding" role="main">
            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->
```

Comment: You should copy an existing template from the theme as a starting point, where is your get_header(); get_footer(); etc. ?

Comment: I don't need for this template @Paul

Comment: If you are using wordpress you need a lot of what's going on in the header and footer wp_head(); & wp_footer(); are essential you also need your <html> and <head> tags if you don't need the html elements in your header and footer then I'd advise you to create a separate header/footer for this template or at least include these essentials to your template.

Comment: Yes you are right, if i add the header and footer i get a friendly page, but i want the template without them and full width.

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: @Paul thanks but it needs some edit, leave some spaces and maybe add some bolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create another header and footer specifically for this template so header-new.php and call with:

```
get_header('new');
```

or else copy the content of the header.php and footer.php into the top and bottom of your template and remove the html elements that you don't need.

The following  tags should **NOT** be ignored in a template:

`<head>` `<html>` `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();`

Comment: I was missing some important libraries and html code with some important css classes which are contained inside Header and footer, that i didn't include in my code